# Is there a way to check sent emails from an application?

Tags: android, email

I've got a series of functions that;

1. Split a folder up into .zips of ~24mb sizes'
2. Creates a button for each zip created associated with that original folder
3. Each button will go into an email intent and attach its associated zip to the email.
4. **Once sent, I'd like to highlight that button to indicate an email has been sent**

All other functions work at runtime (based off the previously created folders)

How can I tell the application that an email has been sent even after restarting the application?

Answer (score 1):

Sending an email through an intent is not supposed to give you any result. It returns after the mail is sent. The Intent for sending a mail therefore should be send via `startActivity`.

`startActivityForResult` will not give you any feedback about the sending process.

edit: As for your comment:

> but I'd like to think of a way where I could start the app up again and recognise some files have been emailed and highlight the buttons accordingly

You could just save the information about which mail was send in your `onSaveInstanceState`

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("isSend", isSend);
```

and restore it when your app restarts with something like:

```
private void restoreData(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("isSend")) {
        isSend = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isSend");
    }
```

Comment: That's fine but it's still temporary, i could just send through the button itself to the function that does the email intent and tell it to change colour at the end of send, but I'd like to think of a way where I could start the app up again and recognise some files have been emailed and highlight the buttons accordingly

Comment: If you want to persist your data after the app restarted you could save the info about which mails were send in `onSaveInstanceState`. I edited my answer.